# Can dynamic programming be used with recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I understand why DP is more efficient over than simple recursion.

However, I understood that DP is recursion using memoization technique.

For Fibonacci, like this :

```
int DP[10000]; //initalized by 0

int f(int num){
    if (DP[num] != 0)
        return DP[num];

    DP[num] = f(num -1) + f(num - 2);
    return DP[num];
}
```

I always use DP in this way of recursion, and it works quite well on algorithm problems like ACM.

Recently, I knew that most people do not use DP in this way.

They use DP like this :

```
int fib(int n)
{
  /* Declare an array to store Fibonacci numbers. */
  int f[n+1];
  int i;

  /* 0th and 1st number of the series are 0 and 1*/
  f[0] = 0;
  f[1] = 1;

  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
      /* Add the previous 2 numbers in the series
         and store it */
      f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
  }

  return f[n];
}
```

*this source is from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/*

---

I don't know this two way's difference.

Are they have same time complexity?

Also, I wonder can my way(recursion + memoization) is called DP?

And is there any disadvantages using my way of DP on algorithm problems?

Comment: Note that your first example isn't quite right, because you forgot to actually memoize!

Comment: You're right, I corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also, I wonder can my way(recursion + memoization) is called DP?

I think it's a borderline case. Cormen et al.'s *Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition* describes your approach (on page 347) as a "variation of dynamic programming", contrasting it with the "ordinary dynamic programming" of the preceding sections, and referring to it as "memoization" or "memoized recursion".

> And is there any disadvantages using my way of DP on algorithm problems?

In your specific example, I think the biggest disadvantage is that you require O(*n*) stack space, which may be a problem in many environments (stack space is often much more limited than heap space). And although the ordinary-DP version that you quote still uses O(*n*) space, I think it's much more obvious how to go from there to a version that uses only O(1) space. (And that's true of many other DP problems as well; for example, the greatest-common-subsequence problem requires only O(*m* + *n*) space, but a memoized recursive solution requires O(*mn*) space.)

On the other hand, your approach may be better in some cases where it's not so obvious exactly which subproblems will actually end up being needed. In that case, the memoized recursion approach avoids solving unnecessary cases.

Comment: Nice. The comparision of stack and heap is cool and also the reducing space. Can you give an example for the last paragraph ? I am still not clear how such a situation is. thx

Comment: Addition: there are terms `top-down DP` for memoization and `bottom-up DP` for the second approach

Comment: So both momoized recursion and ordinary-DP have same time complexity?(In this case O(n), I guess)

Comment: @BlakStar The time in Big O term is the same. If you actually care about the exact constant factor, ordinary-DP is better.

Comment: @cuongptnk: I didn't have a specific example in mind, but here's a problem that I think fits the bill: Given two sequences *s* and *t*, such as *s* = A-B-C-A-B-C-D-E-F-D-E-F and *t* = C-B-C-A-B-F-D-E-F-E-D-A, determine whether there is a binary tree such that *s* is its preorder traversal and *t* is its postorder traversal. I think it would be hard to write an ordinary-DP approach that didn't risk examining many contiguous subsequences that the memoized-recursion approach could simply ignore.

Comment: @ruakh Here is the recursion i can construct : s = A Left Right, t = Left Right A; and length L of Left will be from 0 to 11. Return (OR for L: 0-11 (s[0] == t[last]) && Recursion(s_Left, t_Left) && Recursion(s_Right, t_Right)). 
However, i cannot see anyway to reuse the result of computed sub-problems with the above recursion. Therefore, it is not DP to begin with ?

Comment: @cuongptnk: If you run that recursion over the example I gave, you'll find that there are various pairs of substrings that get re-compared multiple times (unless you memoize).

Comment: @ruakh I see. That is why the example is specially designed with repeated values. The recursion itself does not reveal which substrings to reuse; but a sub-string comparison would identify if we can reuse substrings' results. Nice. Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: @cuongptnk: Not exactly. The repeated values were just so there would be multiple "branches" of deep recursion (i.e., so that for any given `first`, `s[first] == t[last]` could be true for multiple values of `last`); but I'm not suggesting that you should memoize based on the actual *contents* of `s_Left` and `t_Left` and so on. Rather, you should memoize based on `L` and the indices into `s` and `t`. (You can store this in a three-dimensional array.)

Comment: @cuongptnk: (Having thought about it further, a better way to ensure deep recursion is to say that we want a *count* of all possible distinct trees with preorder traversal = *s* and postorder traversal = *t*. The worst-case number of recursions would then be in a sequence like A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A, where naive recursion takes exponential time but dynamic programming or memoized recursion takes polynomial time.)

Comment: @ruakh Nice. Memoize using a hash table would speed up the look-up time. The count query will enforce the checking of all cases; therefore ensure deep recursion.

Comment: @ruakh Actually i don't think memoizing by actual contents of strings is bad. There is a trade off between space and run time here. For the input `A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A`, the space is `O(n^3)` by using the indices. But using actual content, the space is `O(n^2)` (could reduce to `O(n)` if you encode the string).

Comment: @cuongptnk: But memoizing by string contents would increase the cost of lookup from O(1) to at least O(*n*).

Comment: @ruakh Yup. We trade the space with query time. I think there is a balance, where some inputs are good for one, and there are inputs good for other. But, yes, my gut tell me that hashing table is better in most case (need a more complicated analysis to be sure).